# Auto Radio Button Select

Tags: javascript

I am no good with HTML, but I have this script below which I am trying to make correct.

```
if (form.getAnswerText('total') <=1) {
  form.Radioset("radio").checked = 1;
} else {
  if (form.getAnswerText('agreement') >=1) {
     form.Radioset("radio").checked = 0;
}
```

The purpose of this script above is as follows.

I have a text field which has a field ID "Total". This text field currently produces a total number. 
I have a radio question field, which has a field ID "radio". Within this radio button I have two options "yes(Score 1)" or "no(Score 0)". Both of these options have a radio button score of "0" and "1"

So the script above is supposed to work in this way: If the "total number" is greater than 1, the radio question will select the score "1" and the same if the total less than 1.

Thank you
Joseph

Comment: if (form.getAnswerText('total') <=1) 
{ 
form.Radioset("radio").checked = 1;
}
else
{
if (form.getAnswerText('agreement') >=1) 
{
form.Radioset("radio").checked = 0;
}

Comment: mind that this is *Javascript* not *Java* (your initial tag). You must know the difference if you want to code.

Comment: That was a typo there, thank you for spotting. I am using JavaScript.

Comment: ok did the answer help?

Comment: The 1 represents the radio option score, in this case I have two options within this radio question. These are "Yes" or "No". The script is looking for the score. Yes has a radio button score of 1 and No has a radio button score 0.

Answer (score 0):

Look if it can help:

1. You are missing a close parenthesis for you last `if`
2. You assign 1
   to the `radio` button when the `total` is *less or equal* to 1, maybe you
   meant `=>` istead? of `<=`?